# CSS Breaks when HTML is put inside a div

Tags: html, css

I want to put my code inside a container div so I can put it in the middle of the page and center align it. However, when I put my spans within the container it seems to invalidate my CSS. Can anyone please show me how I can change the CSS to apply to new my code in the most correct way possible.

**CSS**

```
#featurenav {
    background:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    height:50px;
    padding:0 1em;
    transition:0.3s;
}
#featurenav > span {
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:1em;
    margin-right:1em;
    opacity:.5;
}
#featurenav > span.active {
    opacity:1;
}
#featurenav.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
}
```

**OLD HTML**

```
<nav id="featurenav">
    <span class='a1'>Section 1</span>
    <span class='a2'>Section 2</span>
    <span class='a3'>Section 3</span>
</nav>
```

**NEW HTML**

```
<nav id="featurenav">
<div class="container">
    <span class='a1'>Section 1</span>
    <span class='a2'>Section 2</span>
    <span class='a3'>Section 3</span>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Eiter remove `>` sign or add `.container` before `>` then it should work

Comment: It doesn’t “break” your CSS – the selector just doesn’t match any elements any more. `>` is the _child_ combinator, and with your new HTML structure the `span` elements _are not_ children of `#featurenav` any more. So you have to adapt it accordingly – which is possible in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using the [direct descendant/child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) `>` for the styling of your spans. When you wrap the spans with an additional `<div>`, they will no longer be the direct descendants of `#featurenav`. Use this instead:

```
#featurenav span {
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:1em;
    margin-right:1em;
    opacity:.5;
}
#featurenav span.active {
    opacity:1;
}
```

If you, however, want to be very strict with how descendants are selected (i.e. you only want to select for `<span>` nested two levels down from `#featurenav`), then you should use this instead, although I don't see it being necessary based on your markup, unless you have other spans within `#featurenav`.

```
#featurenav > div > span {
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:1em;
    margin-right:1em;
    opacity:.5;
}
#featurenav > div > span.active {
    opacity:1;
}
```